# multiple p:ajax in one h:form not invoking

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<h:form>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">

            <h:outputText value="Region: " />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="regionSelection" value="#{haf.selectedRegion}" effect="fade">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{haf.regions}" var="region"
                    itemLabel="#{region.regionName}" itemValue="#{region.regionCode}" />
                <p:ajax listener="#{haf.selectRegion}" update="provinceSelection" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputText value="Province: " />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="provinceSelection" value="#{haf.selectedProvince}" effect="fade">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{haf.provinces}" var="province"
                    itemLabel="#{province.provName}" itemValue="#{province.provCode}" />
                <p:ajax listener="#{haf.selectProvince}" update="citySelection" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputText value="City/Municipality: " />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="citySelection" value="#{haf.selectedCity}" effect="fade">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{haf.cities}" var="city"
                    itemLabel="#{city.cityName}" itemValue="#{city.cityCode}" />
                <p:ajax listener="#{haf.selectCity }" update="brgySelection" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputText value="Barangay: " />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="brgySelection" value="#{haf.selectedBrgy}"
                effect="fade">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{haf.brgys}" var="brgy"
                    itemLabel="#{brgy.brgyName}" itemValue="#{brgy.brgyCode}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

May I ask what is the problem of the about code... the first ajax fires but the second doesn't. Does JSF have rule, 1 form, 1 ajax? Thanks in advance for answering a naive question.

Comment: it has to work. i have done same thing before.

Comment: sori for this question, I just didnt annotate the 'haf' with ViewScoped. X)